# why do i get error for creating an object?

Tags: python

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, ids):
        self.ids = ids

    rahul = Person(100)
```

error:

```
   rahul = Person(100)    
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

can someone please tell me what the problem is with this simple code?

Comment: The indentation is wrong - you're trying to assign a new `Person` to `rahul` **before you finish defining the class**.

Comment: Leave this question open.  In response to the close votes, I don't think this is typographical error.  I think it's a conceptual error.  And I commend the OP for writing a question that includes all elements necessary to answer it.

Comment: thanks so much jon;;;;indendation was the problem;;;my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `Person` while the class is still being created (and before the class object is bound to the name `Person`). If `raul` really is supposed to be a class attribute of `Person`, you'll have to assign it after the class is defined.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, ids):
        self.ids = ids

Person.rahul = Person(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that `rahul = Person(100)` isn't supposed to be indented...